# Do I have to use categories?

Tags: categories

I don't want my blog to use "categories" is there a way to turn them off? I can just not define any but then they are still listed as "uncategorized"

Comment: [This question asks how to do this on WordPress.com](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2956/how-to-totally-get-rid-of-category-in-my-blog), but contains some answers on how to remove the category metaboxes - which will only work on self-hosted WordPress installations.

Answer (score 2):

You're not obligated to use categories. The listing of categories is a function of the theme, you can edit your theme and remove that. Depending on the structure of your theme these may be in a number of places. You can search for instances of `get_the_category` and comment them out. Look for a file called `loop.php` first, failing that, your `single.php` and `index.php` files.

*edit:
I should mention, it may be the case that your particular theme doesn't allow you to remove the category listing as easily as I've outlined, if you're using a framework based theme where these functions are removed from the normal template structure for instance. In this case you should seek assistance with the support of whomever developed your theme, or choose another.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a built in hook or filter to unregister a taxonomy (category is a built in WordPress taxonomy).  There is a [trac ticket with a patch](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/11058) but it has not been implemented.

I found a solution on [Kaiser's](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/385/kaiser) Git Hub [Page](https://gist.github.com/franz-josef-kaiser) that allows you to [unregister built in taxonomies.](https://gist.github.com/870890)