# Using pre_get_posts on true pages and static front pages

Tags: pages, pre-get-posts, frontpage

I have done quite extensive research on how to use `pre_get_posts` on true pages and the static front pages, and it seems that there is no fool proof method.

The best option I found to date was from a [post done by @birgire on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22142984/1908141). I have rewritten it into a demo class and made the code a bit more dynamic

```
class PreGeTPostsForPages
{
    /**
     * @var string|int $pageID
     * @access protected     
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    protected $pageID;

    /**
     * @var bool $injectPageIntoLoop
     * @access protected     
     * @since 1.0.0
    */
    protected $injectPageIntoLoop;

    /**
     * @var array $args
     * @access protected     
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    protected $args;

    /**
     * @var int $validatedPageID
     * @access protected     
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    protected $validatedPageID = 0;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param string|int $pageID = NULL
     * @param bool $injectPageIntoLoop = false
     * @param array| $args = []
     * @since 1.0.0
     */     
    public function __construct( 
        $pageID             = NULL, 
        $injectPageIntoLoop = true, 
        $args               = [] 
    ) { 
        $this->pageID             = $pageID;
        $this->injectPageIntoLoop = $injectPageIntoLoop;
        $this->args               = $args;
    }

    /**
     * Private method validatePageID()
     *
     * Validates the page ID passed
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    private function validatePageID()
    {
        $validatedPageID       = filter_var( $this->pageID, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT );
        $this->validatedPageID = $validatedPageID;
    }

    /**
     * Public method init()
     *
     * This method is used to initialize our pre_get_posts action
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    public function init()
    {
        // Load the correct actions according to the value of $this->keepPageIntegrity
        add_action( 'pre_get_posts', [$this, 'preGetPosts'] );
    }

    /**
     * Protected method pageObject()
     *
     * Gets the queried object to use that as page object
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    protected function pageObject()
    {
        global $wp_the_query;
        return $wp_the_query->get_queried_object();
    }

    /**
     * Public method preGetPosts()
     *
     * This is our call back method for the pre_get_posts action.
     * 
     * The pre_get_posts action will only be used if the page integrity is
     * not an issue, which means that the page will be altered to work like a
     * normal archive page. Here you have the option to inject the page object as
     * first post through the_posts filter when $this->injectPageIntoLoop === true
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    public function preGetPosts( \WP_Query $q )
    {
        // Make sure that we are on the main query and the desired page
        if (    is_admin() // Only run this on the front end
             || !$q->is_main_query() // Only target the main query
             || !is_page( $this->validatedPageID ) // Run this only on the page specified
        )
            return;

        // Remove the filter to avoid infinte loops
        remove_filter( current_filter(), [$this, __METHOD__] );

        // METHODS:
        $this->validatePageID();
        $this->pageObject();

        $queryArgs             = $this->args;

        // Set default arguments which cannot be changed 
        $queryArgs['pagename'] = NULL;

        // We have reached this point, lets do what we need to do
        foreach ( $queryArgs as $key=>$value ) 
            $q->set( 
                filter_var( $key, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ),
                $value // Let WP_Query handle the sanitation of the values accordingly
            );

        // Set $q->is_singular to 0 to get pagination to work
        $q->is_singular = false;

        // FILTERS:
        add_filter( 'the_posts',        [$this, 'addPageAsPost'],   PHP_INT_MAX );
        add_filter( 'template_include', [$this, 'templateInclude'], PHP_INT_MAX );  
    }

    /**
     * Public callback method hooked to 'the_posts' filter
     * This will inject the queried object into the array of posts
     * if $this->injectPageIntoLoop === true
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    public function addPageAsPost( $posts )
    {
        // Inject the page object as a post if $this->injectPageIntoLoop == true
        if ( true === $this->injectPageIntoLoop )
            return array_merge( [$this->pageObject()], $posts );

        return $posts;
    }

    /**
     * Public call back method templateInclude() for the template_include filter
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    public function templateInclude( $template )
    {
        // Remove the filter to avoid infinte loops
        remove_filter( current_filter(), [$this, __METHOD__] );

        // Get the page template saved in db
        $pageTemplate = get_post_meta( 
            $this->validatedPageID, 
            '_wp_page_template', 
            true 
        );

        // Make sure the template exists before we load it, but only if $template is not 'default'
        if ( 'default' !== $pageTemplate ) {
            $locateTemplate = locate_template( $pageTemplate );
            if ( $locateTemplate )
                return $template = $locateTemplate;
        }

        /**
         * If $template returned 'default', or the template is not located for some reason,
         * we need to get and load the template according to template hierarchy
         *
         * @uses get_page_template()
         */
        return $template = get_page_template();
    }
}

$init = new PreGeTPostsForPages(
    251, // Page ID
    false,
    [
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'post_type'      => 'post'
    ]
);
$init->init();
```

This works well and page as expected by using [my own pagination function](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/172818/31545).

### ISSUES:

Because of the function, I loose page integrity which stuff other functions relying on the page object stored in `$post`. `$post` before the loop is set to the first post in the loop and `$post` is set to the last post in the loop after the loop, which is expected. What I need is that `$post` is set to the current page object, ie, the queried object.

Also, `$wp_the_query->post` and `$wp_query->post` holds the first post in the loop and not the queried object as on a normal page

I use the following (*outside my class*) to check my globals before and after the loop

```
add_action( 'wp_head',   'printGlobals' );
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'printGlobals' );
function printGlobals()
{
    $global_test  = 'QUERIED OBJECT: ' . $GLOBALS['wp_the_query']->queried_object_id . '</br>';
    $global_test .= 'WP_THE_QUERY: ' . $GLOBALS['wp_the_query']->post->ID . '</br>';
    $global_test .= 'WP_QUERY: ' . $GLOBALS['wp_query']->post->ID . '</br>';
    $global_test .= 'POST: ' . $GLOBALS['post']->ID . '</br>';
    $global_test .= 'FOUND_POSTS: ' . $GLOBALS['wp_query']->found_posts . '</br>';
    $global_test .= 'MAX_NUM_PAGES: ' . $GLOBALS['wp_query']->max_num_pages . '</br>';

    ?><pre><?php var_dump( $global_test ); ?></pre><?php
}
```

### BEFORE THE LOOP:

Before the loop, the problem is partly solved by setting `$injectPageIntoLoop` to true which inject the page object as first page in the loop. This is quite useful if you need to show the page info before the requested posts, but if you don't want that, you are screwed.

I can solve the issue before the loop by directly hacking the globals, which I do not really like. I hook the following method to `wp` inside my `preGetPosts` method

```
public function wp()
{
    $page                          = get_post( $this->pageID );
    $GLOBALS['wp_the_query']->post = $page;
    $GLOBALS['wp_query']           = $GLOBALS['wp_the_query'];
    $GLOBALS['post']               = $page;
}
```

and inside `preGetPosts` method

```
add_action( 'wp', [$this, 'wp'] );
```

From this, `$wp_the_query->post`, `$wp_query->post` and `$post` all holds the page object.

### AFTER THE LOOP

This is where my big issue is, after the loop. After hacking the globals through the `wp` hook and method,

- `$wp_the_query->post` and  `$wp_query->post` is set back to the first post in the loop, as expected
- `$post` is set to the last post in the loop.

What I need is that all three are set back to the queried object/current page object.

I have tried hooking the `wp` method to `loop_end` action, which does not work. Hooking the `wp` method to `get_sidebar` action works, but it is too late.

```
add_action( 'get_sidebar', [$this, 'wp'] );
```

Running `printGlobals()` directly after the loop in the template confirms that as `$wp_the_query->post` and  `$wp_query->post` are still set to the first post and `$post` to the last post.

I can manually add the code inside the `wp` method after the loop inside the template, but the idea is not to alter the template files directly as the class should be transferable in a plugin between themes.

Is there any proper way to solve this issue where one run `pre_get_posts` on a true page and static front page and still keep the integrity of `$wp_the_query->post`, `$wp_query->post`, and `$post` (*having those set to the queried object*) before and after the loop.

### EDIT

There seems to be confusion about what I need and why I need it

**What I need**

I need to retain the values of `$wp_the_query->post`, `$wp_query->post` and `$post` across the template regardless, and that value should be the queried object. At this stage, with the code I have posted, the values of those three variables does not hold the page object, but rather post objects of posts in the loop. I hope that is clear enough.

I have posted code which you can use to test these variables

**Why I need it**

I need a reliable way to add posts via `pre_get_posts` to page templates and static front pages without changing full page functionality. At this stage, as the code in question stands, it breaks my breadcrumb feature and related page feature after the loop due to  `$post` which holds the "wrong" post object.

Most of all, I do not want to alter the page templates directly. I want to be able to add posts to a page template without **ANY** modification to the template

Comment: What are you trying to do, your goals or functional requirements? You don't state it anywhere as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I finally got it working, but not with the code in my question. I totally scrapped that whole idea and restarted going in a new direction.

### NOTE:

If anyone is ever able to sort out the issues in my question, feel free to post an answer. Also, if you have any other solutions, feel free to post an answer.

## REWORKED CLASS AND SOLUTION:

What I tried to do here was to use post injection, rather than completely altering the main query and getting stuck with all the above issues, including (a) directly altering globals, (b) running into the global value issue, and (c) reassigning page templates.

By using post injection, I'm able to keep full post integrity, so  `$wp_the_query->post`, `$wp_query->post`, `$posts` and `$post` stay constant throughout the template. Each of these variables reference the current page object (as is the case with true pages). This way, functions like breadcrumbs know that the current page is a true page and not some kind of archive.

I had to alter the main query slightly (*through filters and actions*) to adjust for pagination though, but we will come to that.

### POST INJECTION QUERY

In order to accomplish post injection, I used a custom query to return the posts needed for injection. I also used the custom query's `$found_pages` property to adjust that of the main query to get pagination working from the main query. Posts are injected into the main query through the `loop_end` action.

In order to make the custom query accessible and usable outside the class, I introduced a couple of actions.

- **Pagination hooks** in order to hook pagination funtions:

  - `pregetgostsforgages_before_loop_pagination`
  - `pregetgostsforgages_after_loop_pagination`
- **Custom counter** which counts the posts in the loop. These actions can be used to alter how posts are displayed inside the loop according to post number.

  - `pregetgostsforgages_counter_before_template_part`
  - `pregetgostsforgages_counter_after_template_part`
- General hook to access the query object and current post object

  - `pregetgostsforgages_current_post_and_object`

These hooks gives you a total hands-off experience, as you do not need to change anything in the page template itself, which was my original intention from the start. A page can completely be altered from a plugin or a function file, which makes this solution very dynamic.

I have also used `get_template_part()` in order to load a template part, which will be used to display the posts. Most themes today make use of template parts, which makes this very useful in the class. If your theme uses `content.php`, you can simply pass `content` to `$templatePart` to load `content.php`.

If you need post format support for template parts, it is easy – you can simply pass `content` to `$templatePart` and set `$postFormatSupport` to `true`. As a result, the template part `content-video.php` will be loaded for a post with a post format of `video`.

### THE MAIN QUERY

The following changes was done to the main query through the respective filters and actions:

- In order to paginate the main query:

  - The injector query's `$found_posts` property value is passed to that of the main query object through the `found_posts` filter.
  - The value of the user passed parameter `posts_per_page` is set to the main query through `pre_get_posts`.
  - `$max_num_pages` is calculated using the amount of posts in `$found_posts`  and `posts_per_page`. Because `is_singular` is true on pages, it inhibits the  `LIMIT` clause being set. Simply setting `is_singular` to false caused a few issues, so I decided to set the `LIMIT` clause through the `post_limits` filter. I kept the `offset` of the `LIMIT` clause set to `0` to avoid 404's on pages with pagination turned on.

This takes care of pagination and any issue that might arise from the post injection.

### THE PAGE OBJECT

The current page object is available to display as a post by using the default loop on the page, separate and on top of the injected posts. If you do not need this, you can simply set `$removePageFromLoop` to true, and this will hide the page content from being displayed.

At this stage, I'm using CSS to hide the page object through the `loop_start` and `loop_end` actions as I cannot find another way of doing this. The downside with this method is that anything hooked to `the_post` action hook inside the main query will also be hidden.

## THE CLASS

The `PreGetPostsForPages` class can be improved and should be properly namespaced as well. While you can simply drop this in your theme's functions file, it would be better to drop this into a custom plugin.

Use, modify and abuse as you see fit. The code is well commented, so it should be easy to follow and adjust

```
class PreGetPostsForPages
{
    /**
     * @var string|int $pageID
     * @access protected     
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    protected $pageID;

    /**
     * @var string $templatePart
     * @access protected     
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    protected $templatePart;

    /**
     * @var bool $postFormatSupport
     * @access protected     
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    protected $postFormatSupport;

    /**
     * @var bool $removePageFromLoop
     * @access protected     
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    protected $removePageFromLoop;

    /**
     * @var array $args
     * @access protected     
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    protected $args;

    /**
     * @var array $mergedArgs
     * @access protected     
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    protected $mergedArgs = [];

    /**
     * @var NULL|\stdClass $injectorQuery
     * @access protected     
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    protected $injectorQuery = NULL;

    /**
     * @var int $validatedPageID
     * @access protected     
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    protected $validatedPageID = 0;

    /** 
     * Constructor method
     *
     * @param string|int $pageID The ID of the page we would like to target
     * @param string $templatePart The template part which should be used to display posts
     * @param string $postFormatSupport Should get_template_part support post format specific template parts
     * @param bool $removePageFromLoop Should the page content be displayed or not
     * @param array $args An array of valid arguments compatible with WP_Query
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */      
    public function __construct( 
        $pageID             = NULL,
        $templatePart       = NULL,
        $postFormatSupport  = false,
        $removePageFromLoop = false,
        $args               = [] 
    ) {
        $this->pageID             = $pageID;
        $this->templatePart       = $templatePart;
        $this->postFormatSupport  = $postFormatSupport;
        $this->removePageFromLoop = $removePageFromLoop;
        $this->args               = $args;
    }

    /**
     * Public method init()
     *
     * The init method will be use to initialize our pre_get_posts action
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    public function init()
    {
        // Initialise our pre_get_posts action
        add_action( 'pre_get_posts', [$this, 'preGetPosts'] );
    }

    /**
     * Private method validatePageID()
     *
     * Validates the page ID passed
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    private function validatePageID()
    {
        $validatedPageID = filter_var( $this->pageID, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT );
        $this->validatedPageID = $validatedPageID;
    }

    /**
     * Private method mergedArgs()
     *
     * Merge the default args with the user passed args
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    private function mergedArgs()
    {
        // Set default arguments
        if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) {
            $currentPage = get_query_var( 'paged' );
        } elseif ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) {
            $currentPage = get_query_var( 'page' );
        } else {
            $currentPage = 1;
        }
        $default = [
            'suppress_filters'    => true,
            'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
            'paged'               => $currentPage,
            'posts_per_page'      => get_option( 'posts_per_page' ), // Set posts per page here to set the LIMIT clause etc
            'nopaging'            => false
        ];    
        $mergedArgs = wp_parse_args( (array) $this->args, $default );
        $this->mergedArgs = $mergedArgs;
    }

    /**
     * Public method preGetPosts()
     *
     * This is the callback method which will be hooked to the 
     * pre_get_posts action hook. This method will be used to alter
     * the main query on the page specified by ID.
     *
     * @param \stdClass WP_Query The query object passed by reference
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    public function preGetPosts( \WP_Query $q )
    {
        if (    !is_admin() // Only target the front end
             && $q->is_main_query() // Only target the main query
             && $q->is_page( filter_var( $this->validatedPageID, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT ) ) // Only target our specified page
        ) {
            // Remove the pre_get_posts action to avoid unexpected issues
            remove_action( current_action(), [$this, __METHOD__] );

            // METHODS:
            // Initialize our method which will return the validated page ID
            $this->validatePageID();
            // Initiale our mergedArgs() method
            $this->mergedArgs();
            // Initiale our custom query method
            $this->injectorQuery();

            /**
             * We need to alter a couple of things here in order for this to work
             * - Set posts_per_page to the user set value in order for the query to
             *   to properly calculate the $max_num_pages property for pagination
             * - Set the $found_posts property of the main query to the $found_posts
             *   property of our custom query we will be using to inject posts
             * - Set the LIMIT clause to the SQL query. By default, on pages, `is_singular` 
             *   returns true on pages which removes the LIMIT clause from the SQL query.
             *   We need the LIMIT clause because an empty limit clause inhibits the calculation
             *   of the $max_num_pages property which we need for pagination
             */
            if (    $this->mergedArgs['posts_per_page'] 
                 && true !== $this->mergedArgs['nopaging']
            ) {
                $q->set( 'posts_per_page', $this->mergedArgs['posts_per_page'] );
            } elseif ( true === $this->mergedArgs['nopaging'] ) {
                $q->set( 'posts_per_page', -1 );
            }

            // FILTERS:
            add_filter( 'found_posts', [$this, 'foundPosts'], PHP_INT_MAX, 2 );
            add_filter( 'post_limits', [$this, 'postLimits']);

            // ACTIONS:
            /**
             * We can now add all our actions that we will be using to inject our custom
             * posts into the main query. We will not be altering the main query or the 
             * main query's $posts property as we would like to keep full integrity of the 
             * $post, $posts globals as well as $wp_query->post. For this reason we will use
             * post injection
             */     
            add_action( 'loop_start', [$this, 'loopStart'], 1 );
            add_action( 'loop_end',   [$this, 'loopEnd'],   1 );
        }    
    }    

    /**
     * Public method injectorQuery
     *
     * This will be the method which will handle our custom
     * query which will be used to 
     * - return the posts that should be injected into the main
     *   query according to the arguments passed
     * - alter the $found_posts property of the main query to make
     *   pagination work 
     *
     * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @return \stdClass $this->injectorQuery
     */
    public function injectorQuery()
    {
        //Define our custom query
        $injectorQuery = new \WP_Query( $this->mergedArgs );

        // Update the thumbnail cache
        update_post_thumbnail_cache( $injectorQuery );

        $this->injectorQuery = $injectorQuery;

        return $this->injectorQuery;
    }

    /**
     * Public callback method foundPosts()
     * 
     * We need to set found_posts in the main query to the $found_posts
     * property of the custom query in order for the main query to correctly 
     * calculate $max_num_pages for pagination
     *
     * @param string $found_posts Passed by reference by the filter
     * @param stdClass \WP_Query Sq The current query object passed by refence
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @return $found_posts
     */
    public function foundPosts( $found_posts, \WP_Query $q )
    {
        if ( !$q->is_main_query() )
            return $found_posts;

        remove_filter( current_filter(), [$this, __METHOD__] );

        // Make sure that $this->injectorQuery actually have a value and is not NULL
        if (    $this->injectorQuery instanceof \WP_Query 
             && 0 != $this->injectorQuery->found_posts
        )
            return $found_posts = $this->injectorQuery->found_posts;

        return $found_posts;
    }

    /**
     * Public callback method postLimits()
     *
     * We need to set the LIMIT clause as it it is removed on pages due to 
     * is_singular returning true. Witout the limit clause, $max_num_pages stays
     * set 0 which avoids pagination. 
     *
     * We will also leave the offset part of the LIMIT cluase to 0 to avoid paged
     * pages returning 404's
     *
     * @param string $limits Passed by reference in the filter
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @return $limits
     */
    public function postLimits( $limits )
    {
        $posts_per_page = (int) $this->mergedArgs['posts_per_page'];
        if (    $posts_per_page
             && -1   !=  $posts_per_page // Make sure that posts_per_page is not set to return all posts
             && true !== $this->mergedArgs['nopaging'] // Make sure that nopaging is not set to true
        ) {
            $limits = "LIMIT 0, $posts_per_page"; // Leave offset at 0 to avoid 404 on paged pages
        }

        return $limits;
    }

    /**
     * Public callback method loopStart()
     *
     * Callback function which will be hooked to the loop_start action hook
     *
     * @param \stdClass \WP_Query $q Query object passed by reference
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    public function loopStart( \WP_Query $q )
    {
        /**
         * Although we run this action inside our preGetPosts methods and
         * and inside a main query check, we need to redo the check here aswell
         * because failing to do so sets our div in the custom query output as well
         */

        if ( !$q->is_main_query() )
            return;

        /** 
         * Add inline style to hide the page content from the loop
         * whenever $removePageFromLoop is set to true. You can
         * alternatively alter the page template in a child theme by removing
         * everything inside the loop, but keeping the loop
         * Example of how your loop should look like:
         *     while ( have_posts() ) {
         *     the_post();
         *         // Add nothing here
         *     }
         */
        if ( true === $this->removePageFromLoop )
            echo '<div style="display:none">';
    }   

    /**
     * Public callback method loopEnd()
     *
     * Callback function which will be hooked to the loop_end action hook
     *
     * @param \stdClass \WP_Query $q Query object passed by reference
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    public function loopEnd( \WP_Query $q )
    {  
        /**
         * Although we run this action inside our preGetPosts methods and
         * and inside a main query check, we need to redo the check here as well
         * because failing to do so sets our custom query into an infinite loop
         */
        if ( !$q->is_main_query() )
            return;

        // See the note in the loopStart method  
        if ( true === $this->removePageFromLoop )
            echo '</div>';

        //Make sure that $this->injectorQuery actually have a value and is not NULL
        if ( !$this->injectorQuery instanceof \WP_Query )
            return; 

        // Setup a counter as wee need to run the custom query only once    
        static $count = 0;    

        /**
         * Only run the custom query on the first run of the loop. Any consecutive
         * runs (like if the user runs the loop again), the custom posts won't show.
         */
        if ( 0 === (int) $count ) {      
            // We will now add our custom posts on loop_end
            $this->injectorQuery->rewind_posts();

            // Create our loop
            if ( $this->injectorQuery->have_posts() ) {

                /**
                 * Fires before the loop to add pagination.
                 *
                 * @since 1.0.0
                 *
                 * @param \stdClass $this->injectorQuery Current object (passed by reference).
                 */
                do_action( 'pregetgostsforgages_before_loop_pagination', $this->injectorQuery );


                // Add a static counter for those who need it
                static $counter = 0;

                while ( $this->injectorQuery->have_posts() ) {
                    $this->injectorQuery->the_post(); 

                    /**
                     * Fires before get_template_part.
                     *
                     * @since 1.0.0
                     *
                     * @param int $counter (passed by reference).
                     */
                    do_action( 'pregetgostsforgages_counter_before_template_part', $counter );

                    /**
                     * Fires before get_template_part.
                     *
                     * @since 1.0.0
                     *
                     * @param \stdClass $this->injectorQuery-post Current post object (passed by reference).
                     * @param \stdClass $this->injectorQuery Current object (passed by reference).
                     */
                    do_action( 'pregetgostsforgages_current_post_and_object', $this->injectorQuery->post, $this->injectorQuery );

                    /** 
                     * Load our custom template part as set by the user
                     * 
                     * We will also add template support for post formats. If $this->postFormatSupport
                     * is set to true, get_post_format() will be automatically added in get_template part
                     *
                     * If you have a template called content-video.php, you only need to pass 'content'
                     * to $template part and then set $this->postFormatSupport to true in order to load
                     * content-video.php for video post format posts
                     */
                    $part = '';
                    if ( true === $this->postFormatSupport )
                        $part = get_post_format( $this->injectorQuery->post->ID ); 

                    get_template_part( 
                        filter_var( $this->templatePart, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ), 
                        $part
                    );

                    /**
                     * Fires after get_template_part.
                     *
                     * @since 1.0.0
                     *
                     * @param int $counter (passed by reference).
                     */
                    do_action( 'pregetgostsforgages_counter_after_template_part', $counter );

                    $counter++; //Update the counter
                }

                wp_reset_postdata();

                /**
                 * Fires after the loop to add pagination.
                 *
                 * @since 1.0.0
                 *
                 * @param \stdClass $this->injectorQuery Current object (passed by reference).
                 */
                do_action( 'pregetgostsforgages_after_loop_pagination', $this->injectorQuery );
            }
        }

        // Update our static counter
        $count++;       
    }
}
```

### USAGE

You can now initiate the class (*also in your plugin or functions file*) as follow to target the page with ID 251, upon which we will show 2 posts per page from the `post` post type.

```
$query = new PreGetPostsForPages(
    251,       // Page ID we will target
    'content', //Template part which will be used to display posts, name should be without .php extension 
    true,      // Should get_template_part support post formats
    false,     // Should the page object be excluded from the loop
    [          // Array of valid arguments that will be passed to WP_Query/pre_get_posts
        'post_type'      => 'post', 
        'posts_per_page' => 2
    ] 
);
$query->init();
```

### ADDING PAGINATION AND CUSTOM STYLING

As I mentioned previously, there are a few actions in the injector query in order to add pagination and/or custom styling.

In the following example, I added pagination after the loop using [my own pagination function from the linked answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/172818/31545). Also, using my custom counter, I added a `<div>` to to display my posts in two columns.

Here are the actions I used

```
add_action( 'pregetgostsforgages_counter_before_template_part', function ( $counter )
{
    $class = $counter%2  ? ' right' : ' left';
    echo '<div class="entry-column' . $class . '">';
});

add_action( 'pregetgostsforgages_counter_after_template_part', function ( $counter )
{
    echo '</div>';
});

add_action( 'pregetgostsforgages_after_loop_pagination', function ( \WP_Query $q )
{
    paginated_numbers();    
});
```

Note that pagination is set by the main query, not the injector query, so built-in functions like `the_posts_pagination()` should also work.

This is the end result

[image]

### STATIC FRONT PAGES

Everything works as expected on static front pages together with my pagination function without requiring any further modification.

### CONCLUSION

This might seem like a lot of overhead, and it might be, but the pro's outweigh the con's big time.

**BIG PRO'S**

- You do not need to alter the page template for the specific page in any way. This makes everything dynamic and can easily be transferred between themes without making modifications to the code whatsoever, so long as everything is done in a plugin.
- At most, you only need to create a `content.php` template part in your theme if your theme does not have one yet.
- Any pagination that works on the main query will work on the page without any type of alteration or anything extra from the query being passed to function.

There are more pro's which I cannot think of now, but these are the important ones.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/LTfLK.gif