# Pagination causes error 404 when used with front-page.php

Tags: wp-query, pagination, 404-error, frontpage

I am creating `front-page.php`. This page will display the latest featureed posts, and will also have pagination option to go to the previous featured posts.

I wrote the code for frontpage as follows

```
$args = array();
$args['post_type'] = 'post';
$args['post_status'] = 'publish';
$args['category_name'] = 'featured';
$args['posts_per_page'] = 4
$args['paged'] = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;

$the_query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($the_query->have_posts()) {

    while ($the_query->have_posts()) {

        $the_query->the_post() ;
        the_title();

    } // End of: while ($the_query->have_posts())

    next_posts_link('Next', $the_query->max_num_pages );
    previous_posts_link('Previous');

} // End of: if ($the_query->have_posts())
```

So, when I go to the front page of the site (e.g., to the page `mysite.dev`, the page is displayed properly.

Now, when I click on the `Next` link, the url becomes `mysite.dev/page/2` however, the `404` page is returned instead of the second page of `front-page.php`

I spent about 5 or 6 hours. Read almost single artrticle about this issue and still at loss.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### EDIT

From your comments, `front-page.php` is only used when a page is set as a static front page. Normal home pages, ie, when *Front page displays* is set to *Your latest posts*, `index.php` is used.

All archive pages and the front page uses `paged` and not `page`, so you would need to set `get_query_var( 'page' )` to `get_query_var( 'paged' )`.

Any ways, you should not be using a custom query on your home page, you should be using `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query to your needs

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q )
{
    if (    $q->is_home()
         && $q->is_main_query()
    ) {
        $q->set( 'category_name',  'featured' );
        $q->set( 'posts_per_page', 4          );
    }
});
```

Your pagination links should then be

```
next_posts_link( 'Next' );
previous_posts_link( 'Previous' );
```

Your loop in `index.php` should look like this

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();

           // Your markup and template tags

    }
}
```

If you really need to use `front-page.php` as a normal home page and not a static front page, then you need to do the following

- Change your loop to what I have suggested above with the pagination links
- Use `pre_get_posts` as suggested as above to change the main query according to your need
- Use the `home_template` filter to use `front-page.php` as your homepage template

You can try the following

```
add_filter( 'home_template', function ( $template )
{
    $locate_template = locate_template( 'front-page.php' );

    if ( !$locate_template )
        return $template;

    return $locate_template;
});
```

### ORIGINAL ANSWER

The functions `next_posts_link()` and `previous_posts_link()` don't work on static front pages out of the box. The issue is, pagination uses `get_query_var( 'paged' )` which is saved in the `$paged` global. Because static front pages uses  `get_query_var( 'page' )` and not `get_query_var( 'paged' )`, your links will never paginate past page 1.

We can trick `next_posts_link()` and `previous_posts_link()` to think they are used on an archive page by setting the `$paged` global to `get_query_var( 'page' )`.

You can try the following

```
$paged                   = get_query_var( 'page', 1 ); 
$args                    = [];
$args['post_type']       = 'post';
$args['post_status']     = 'publish';
$args['category_name']   = 'featured';
$args['posts_per_page']  = 4;
$args['paged']           = $paged;

$the_query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($the_query->have_posts()) {

    while ($the_query->have_posts()) {

        $the_query->the_post() ;
        the_title();

    } // End of: while ($the_query->have_posts())

    next_posts_link('Next', $the_query->max_num_pages );
    previous_posts_link('Previous');

    wp_reset_postdata(); // VERY VERY IMPORTANT

} // End of: if ($the_query->have_posts())
```

### EDIT

You can also make use of the following on your static front page

```
$query = new PreGetPostsForPages(
    251,       // Page ID we will target, your static front page ID
    'content', //Template part which will be used to display posts, name should be without .php extension 
    false,     // Should get_template_part support post formats
    true,      // Should the page object be excluded from the loop
    [          // Array of valid arguments that will be passed to WP_Query/pre_get_posts
        'post_type'      => 'post', 
        'category_name'  => 'featured',
        'posts_per_page' => 4
    ] 
);
$query->init();
```

where the `PreGetPostsForPages` class is supported by [my answer here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/215027/31545)

```
add_action( 'pregetgostsforgages_after_loop_pagination', function ()
{
    $paged = get_query_var( 'page', 1 );
    next_posts_link( 'Next' );
    previous_posts_link( 'Previous' );
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But the problem is it is not even getting to the page, a `404` page is displayed,

Comment: Check again, had a syntax error. Fixed it ;-)

Comment: If that does not work, it might be that you have a bad rewrite or a permalink issue. Back up your `.htaccess` file, delete it, and then visit the permalink settings page and reset your permalinks

Comment: This is an update. Sometimes WP is an a$$. As mentioned in the question, the file I am using is `front-page.php`. Now, when I go to settings and ensure "Front page displays" is set to "Your latest posts", I get the 404 error mentioned above. HOWEVER, when I set "Front page displays" to "Static page", and set the front and posts pages accordingly, and when I click the next page, then I get page 2 in the url, and I do not get the 404 error, but instead page 1 (the front page) is displayed.

Comment: @Greeso Please see my update. Hope this is what you need ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your help. After much thought, I am changing the design. I think your answer helped me realize that `front-page.php` is static by design. It seems that making `front-page.php` with pagination is unatural. I will either use `home.php` for my purpose or make front-page.php` static.. Thanks for your help though.