# Pagination on a custom post type loop

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, pagination

I've read a lot of questions about this topic. None of them solve my issue.

**Poblem**: pagination is shown at page 1 but page 2 returns 404.

The query and loop are in front-page.php:

```
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array(
  'post_type'              => 'trabajo',
  'posts_per_page'         => '2',
  'paged'                  => ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
);

// The Query
$trabajo_query = new WP_Query( $args );
$temp_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query   = NULL;
$wp_query   = $trabajo_query;


// The Loop
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();
        the_title();
    }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
the_posts_navigation();

$wp_query = NULL;
$wp_query = $temp_query;  // Reset
```

Comment: Why are you replacing the main query?

Comment: Because `the_posts_navigation();` only works with main query. This is the normal procedure, as far as I know.

Comment: But why not just use the normal post type archive?

Comment: I need several CPTs for this work: works, news and bio. And I need to show two loops with works and news in the front page.

Comment: refer this answer [How to fix pagination for custom loops?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/120408/125227)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the final answer here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/217534/77722

Page 2 of front page was taking pagination from main query, not from my custom query.

I've taked these actions:

**1. To change name of front-page.php to index.php** in order to get the main query every time page is loaded (even when paginated)

**2. To change main query with pre_get_posts** in order to show posts of my CPT:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q ) {
    if (    $q->is_home() && $q->is_main_query() ) {
        $q->set( 'posts_per_page', 1 );
        $q->set( 'post_type', 'trabajo');
    }
});
```

**3. Do a normal loop in the index.php:**

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();
        the_title();
    }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
the_posts_navigation();
```

Works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

I found here a workaround: [Custom post type pagination 404 fix?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22528/custom-post-type-pagination-404-fix)

Since I don't understand it, I don't mark this question as solved. Any explanation of this will be appreciated.

I must to do two actions together:

1. Set `1` the post limit in the admin>reading dashboard.
2. Add this function:

.

```
add_action( 'parse_query','changept' );
function changept() {
    if( !is_admin() )
        set_query_var( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'trabajo' ) );
    return;
}
```

It works, but I don't know what side effects will have this.

Answer (score -2):

Put this code in functions.php file

```
    function pagination($pages = '', $range = 1) {
        $showitems = ($range * 3) + 1;

        global $paged;
        if (empty($paged))
            $paged = 1;

        if ($pages == '') {
            global $wp_query;
            $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
            if (!$pages) {
                $pages = 1;
            }
        }

        if (1 != $pages) {
            echo "<div class=\"gallery-pagination\">";
            echo '<ul class="pagination">';
//        if ($paged > 2 && $paged > $range + 1 && $showitems < $pages)
//            echo "<a href='" . get_pagenum_link(1) . "'>&laquo; First</a>";
            if ($paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages)
                echo "<a href='" . get_pagenum_link($paged - 1) . "'> << </a>";
//        echo '<ul class="pagination">';
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {

                if (1 != $pages && (!($i >= $paged + $range + 1 || $i <= $paged - $range - 1) || $pages <= $showitems )) {
                    echo ($paged == $i) ? "<li class='active'><a href='javascript:void(0)'>" . $i . "</a></li>" : "<li class='inactive'><a href='" . get_pagenum_link($i) . "'>" . $i . "</a></li>";
                }
            }

            if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages)
                echo "<a href=\"" . get_pagenum_link($paged + 1) . "\"> >> </a>";
            echo '</ul>';

            echo "</div>\n";
        }
    }
```

Put this code in your custom post type page where you want it.

```
<?php
            // Get a list of categories
            $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? absint(get_query_var('paged')) : 1;
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'post_gallery',
                'posts_per_page' => 9,
                'order_by' => 'date',
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'paged' => $paged,
            );

            $new_query = new WP_Query($args);
//             print_r($new_query);
            ?>
<?php if (function_exists("pagination")) { ?>
                <?php pagination($new_query->max_num_pages); ?>
            <?php } ?>
```

Comment: This is not a useful answer, you should explain what changes this code has and how it solved the question asker's problem.