# Adding a blog archive with pagination using WP_Query

Tags: posts, wp-query

I have the following code:-

```
<!-- News Archive -->
<div id="news-archive">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12"> 
        <?php
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $args = array(
          'post_type'       => 'post',
          'orderby'         => 'title',
          'order'           => 'ASC',
          'cat'             => '8',
          'offset'          => 2,
          'posts_per_page'  => 6,
          'paged'           => $paged
        );
        $loop = new WP_Query($args);
        $post_counter = 1;
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                <div id="blog-<?php echo $post_counter; ?>" class="blog-wrapper">
                    <?php if(get_the_post_thumbnail()) {
                        the_post_thumbnail();
                    } else {
                    $category = "/wp-content/themes/irongate/assets/img/" . get_field('group_category') . '-default.jpg'; ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo $category; ?>" />      
                    <?php } ?>
                    <span class="news-archive-date"><?php echo get_the_date('d M Y'); ?></span>
                    <p class="news-archive-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
                    <span id="<?php echo $case_category; ?>-logo" class="<?php echo get_field('group_category') == 'inone' ? 'inone-catergory' : 'news-archive-catergory';?>"></span>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <div class="news-overlay blog-overlay">
                            <span class="news-overlay-excerpt"><?php echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0,240); ?>...</span>
                            <span id="careers-overlay-more" class="btn-white">Read more</span>
                        </div>
                    </a>                
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php if($post_counter % 3 == 0) {echo '<div class="clearfix"></div>';} 
        $post_counter++;  
        endwhile; ?><!-- News Archive -->
        <div class="navigation">
            <div class="alignleft"><?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Previous') ?></div>
            <div class="alignright"><?php next_posts_link('More &raquo;') ?></div>
        </div>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The display of the posts is showing correctly as 6 blog posts and the 'More...' button appears but when clicked it just reloads the same content.

How can I add pagination to my blog posts? i.e. clicking next... will show posts 9-14 instead of 2-8 (as I'm using an offset of 2).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `offset` breaks pagination, so you manually need to recalculate pagination. Also, why are you running a custom query\

Comment: Before I forget, `next_posts_link()` are by default set to the main query, and not your custom query

Comment: ok, so what is the correct function? I've removed the offset as well @PieterGoosen

Comment: It depends, if this is suppose to be the main query, you need to use the default loop and `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query according to your needs

Comment: @PieterGoosen this is in a page-template and not the main query

Comment: Then read my second comment :-). Also, is that page used as a page or a static front page. if used as a static front page, then your query var is wrong, it should be `page`

Comment: Nah it's neither a frontpage or blog page :)

Comment: meaning `next_posts_link` wouldn't work right?

Comment: I wonder, this being a normal page, you can try to use my [`PreGetPostsForPages` Class](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/215027/31545) to alter the main query and inject your custom posts in there

Comment: Interesting, I'll have a play with this tonight, do I use the same code that I have in my `template-news.php` template file for the blog posts? @PieterGoosen - this is the content that is in my original question

Comment: Why the downvote with no justification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can calculate `offset` via `paged` and `posts_per_page`. E.g:

```
$per_page = 6;
$paged    = get_query_var('paged') ? : 1;
$offset   = (1 === $paged) ? 0 : (($paged - 1) * $per_page) + (($paged - 1) * 2);

$args = array(
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'paged' => $paged,
  'offset' => $offset,
  'orderby' => 'ID',
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => $per_page,
  'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);

while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
  echo get_the_title() . '<br>';
endwhile;

previous_posts_link('&laquo; Previous', $query->max_num_pages);
if ($paged > 1) echo ' | ';
next_posts_link('More &raquo;', $query->max_num_pages);

echo '<br> Showing ' . $offset . '-' . ($offset + 6) . ' of ' . $query->found_posts . ' posts.';

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Note that the loop start at index 0, so if we ignore sticky posts and only display 6 posts per page, the result on page 2 should be 8-14 instead 9-14 as you expected.

Comment: Ps:  We can set the default value with `get_query_var('paged', 1 )`. Wonder about the default `0` offset here, it looks like we would then miss out items #7 and #8 in that case. I think it's not necessary to set the `paged` in `WP_Query` when we use `offset`? The `$query->found_posts` might be relevant here instead of `count( $query->posts)`.

Comment: @birgire I thought that OP want to skip two posts then I added 2 to the `offset`. ;-) Didn't know about the `$default` param in `get_query_var()`. Thank you for showing me that!

Answer (score 1):

If you are useing [next_posts_link()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link) && [previous_posts_link()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_posts_link) on your custom Query then you have to pass $max_pages parameter. like ->

```
previous_posts_link( '&laquo; Previous', $loop->max_num_pages );
next_posts_link( '&laquo; Previous', $loop->max_num_pages );
```

Or if you want to use just previous_posts_link( '« Previous'); without useing $max_pages parameter then you have to use default query instead custom query. And it's better to used default one. see more details [When to use WP_query(), query_posts() and pre_get_posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use paginate_links:

```
//First get a count of how many pages you'll be producing:

$cat_id = 8;
$per_page = 6;

$all_posts = get_term_by( 'id', $cat_id, 'category' );
$posts_count = $all_posts->count ;
$total_pages = intval( $posts_count / $per_page ) + 1;

$current_page = max(1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) );

echo '<div class="pagination">' ;

echo paginate_links(array(
    //several different ways to do the base variable in my observation/experience
    'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
    'current' => $current_page,
    'total' => $total_pages,
    //if you like the double arrow (Euro quotes) format
    'prev_text' => '&laquo; Previous',
    'next_text' => 'Next &raquo;' 
) );

echo '</div>' ;
```

Some variations may be required depending on your permalinks style, and you can find a lot of interesting formatting for the links themselves based on available parameters and standard or customized output, but I think this should answer the basic question. See ttps://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links for other basic examples.