# Display posts of only a certain category in WP Admin section?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, categories, wp-admin

I want to add a new menu point to post that shows posts of a certain category. Adding a new page is easy if it is just a new post type. But I want to only show posts with a specific category and when updating posts make sure the category is checked.

IS there no way of doing this? I was hoping for some simple functon, like the way register_post_type() does it. As there doesn't seem to be, does anyone give me any tips about how to do this? Is it even possible? Or should I just use a custom post type?

Comment: Yes, of course it is possible to [list posts of a certain category](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters)! But to clarify your problem, can you elaborate what you mean by "I want to add a new menu point"?

Comment: I want a page exactly like all posts, but one that only shows records from category x. I also want to use the update post filter to make sure that on this page items have category x selected.I know there is a cat query string var, but how can I add a new page as a subpage of posts that just lists all posts of category x???

Something like this maybe???
wp_create_list_table({cat: 'x'}); I can see how to add a subpage, but I have to create the content manually... but how??? What methods need to be called to do everything the all posts page does?

Comment: Just to clarify, this is for the backend (admin) not the front end.

Comment: I apologize if you answered this and I didn't catch the answer, or if I'm misunderstanding your issue. But why couldn't you just use the category filter from the all-posts listing?

Comment: Because some clients want a separate page for the category, they have loads of posts. I suggested using that filter but they just want a link to a page that is all setup.

Comment: Milo's answer does what you want, but why not use a custom post type? If the posts in that category are completely separate to other posts then it makes sense that they should be in their own post type.

Comment: Yeah I thought about that but wasn't sure if it was necessary. Is it normal for WP sites to create lots of custom post types? I thought maybe you should only do that if absoultely necessary. I come from a TYPO3 background so I'm still trying to discover the Wordpress way of doing stuff. Thanks for your help, I accepted Milos answer for this.

Comment: I'd always use a custom post type in cases like this. Rather than questioning if a custom post type is necessary, I'd ask myself why it's necessary to create a separate admin page for posts in a certain category when I can just use a custom post type to achieve the exact functionality required. This is why WordPress added custom post types :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter the posts list by appending `?category_name=xx` to the admin posts list URL, and you can add a submenu page with that URL as the target via `add_submenu_page`:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wpd_admin_menu_item' );
function wpd_admin_menu_item(){
    add_submenu_page(
        'edit.php',
        'Page title',
        'Menu item title',
        'edit_posts', 
        'edit.php?category_name=somecat'
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop posts by category name or ID:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => 'staff' ) );
```

or

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => 4 ) );
```

and just use good old fashion way to loop:

```
if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        get_title();
    endwhile;
else :
    echo 'No posts';
endif;
```

You need to create new custom template, get category ID, setup ID in new WP_Query and loop that.

Here is one documentation of how to use [WP_Query()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: Thanks, I know about the query. I'm looking to not do everything manually, there must be some API method that draws the "all posts" or "pages" pages, that I can just provide some kind of argument to to only show post that are in category "x"?

Comment: Realy don't know any plugin for that. I think exists but you need to look. Some templates support that but my suggestion for you is to just made new custm template, copy 1:1 some original code from your template and just adjust query code.

Answer (score 0):

The Category Posts Widget plugin will do this. https://wordpress.org/plugins/category-posts/

> Category Posts Widget is a light widget designed to do one thing and do it well: display the most recent posts from a certain category.

[Documentation](http://tiptoppress.com/category-posts-widget/documentation-4-7/?utm_source=wordpress_org&utm_campaign=documentation_4_7_cpw&utm_medium=web) for how to use it.

and

If you want to see how they did it, then this is their [github repo](https://github.com/tiptoppress/category-posts-widget) .