# Display selected categories onto post page

Tags: posts, categories

I need to know how to display only the selected categories per post page..

Example. I am working on a website for movies. I have a category called Genre, then I have sub categories attached to that like comedy, horror etc...

Then I have a category called Availability and sub categories with like, USA, Mexico, England.. etc..

So I'll need to have it set like this per post page.

**Genres**
Action/Adventure, Drama, New Releases

**Availability**
Untied States, England, France

I have this code, but I can't figure out how to separate between genre and Availability

```
<?php
$categories = get_the_category();
$separator = ' ';
$output = '';
if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
    foreach( $categories as $category ) {
        $output .= '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'View all posts in %s', 'textdomain' ), $category->name ) ) . '">' . esc_html( $category->name ) . '</a>' . $separator;
    }
    echo trim( $output, $separator );
} ?>
```

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/231976/is-there-a-way-to-list-posts-of-only-a-certain-category

Answer (score 1):

If what I understand from your question is correct. You have a post that categorized in multiple categories and subcategories. I have already made the same in a website. use these following code bellow so a sub categories will displayed after the parent category.

```
//first  part
$allcats = get_the_category();
$parent_id = $all_ids = array();

foreach ($allcats as $cats) {
    //get all category id first
    $all_ids[] = $cats->term_id;

    // get top parent category
    if ($cats->category_parent === 0 ) {
        $parent_id[] =  $cats->term_id;
    }
}

//second part
$separator = ' &raquo; ';
$term_ids = implode( ',' , $all_ids );

$hiearchy_cat  = '';
foreach ($parent_id as $parents) {
    $parent_name    = get_cat_name($parents);
    $parent_link    = get_category_link($parents);
    $parent_cat     = '<span class="parent"><a href="'.$parent_link.'">'.$parent_name.'</a></span>';

    //get all sub category with certain ids
    $child_cats = wp_list_categories(
        array(
        'child_of' =>  $parents, 
        'title_li' => '',
        'style'    => 'none',
        'echo'     => false,
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'include'  => $term_ids,

        )
    );
    $child_cats = rtrim( trim( str_replace( '<br />',  $separator, $child_cats ) ), $separator );
    $hiearchy_cat .= '<b>'.$parent_cat.'</b> &raquo; '.$child_cats.'<br>';
}

//last output   
echo $hiearchy_cat;
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I'm not too good with php. With your code, could you alter it to display the Childs of "Genre" titled Genre and the childs of "Territories" titles Availability.   Is this possible?

Comment: just try put it in your single.php and it output will be like your question. please let me know if any errors

Comment: added to single.php added the  <?php   ?>   symbols and nothing happens.. My post pages do not display the sub categories.  I'm trying to make it like this example here.     http://summerhillfilms.com/bills-diary/    If you scroll below the movie synopsis you'll see two sub categories. Genres and Territories. Territories is named Availabilities here.    Also I am using SiteOrigin Page Builder on every post page, not sure if that matters.

Comment: it's a bit weird if that shown nothing. What about replace my code with your existing code in the same place ?

Comment: I got it working with a different code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you view my main post at the bottom, I added another question about the same topic

Comment: @Timothy Rooker please post a new question for your other inquiry. Each post should be limited to one question. If you need to add supplemental information to your original question, please [edit it](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/268373/edit).